# Nodejs loop with callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying retrieve info for 2 items and the user info for each item (a,b,c) with the following code. However im having an issue where it shows duplicate results and unexpected output.

- findItem a
- findUser a
- findUser a
- findItem c
- findUser c
- results
- findItem b
- findUser b
- results
- findUser b
- results

(There is only 1 item for item 'c')

I was expecting to see results only once.

```
var results = [];
var items = ['a', 'b', 'c']; 

function async(item, callback) {        
  findSomething(2, item, function(err, items){
    if (err) throw err; 
    console.log('findItem ' + item);
    var item = [];
    _.map(items, function(value, key) {
      findSomethingElse(items[key].id, function(err, name){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('findUser ' + item);
        item['name'] = name;            
        item['items'] = items[key];            
        callback(item);
      });  
    });      
  });
} 

function final() { 
  console.log('results');
  // return results;
}

function series(item) {
  if(item) {
    async(item, function(result) {
      results.push(result);
      return series(items.shift());
    });
  } else {
    return final();
  }
}
series(items.shift());
```

As suggested I have tried using the async module and have this code correctly showing the items and users, but im unsure how to make the callback to display the results array in the done() function.

```
var results = [];
var items = ['a', 'b', 'c']; 

async.each(items, findItem, function(err){
  if(err) throw err;
}); 

function findItem(item) { 
  Bid.findBids(2, item, function(err, bids){
    if (err) throw err; 
    async.each(bids, findUser, function(err){
      if(err) throw err;
    });
  });
}

function findUser(item) {
  User.findBidder(item.email, function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;
    var bid = [];
    bid['user'] = user;            
    bid['item'] = item;           
    results.push(bid);
  });
}    

function done() { 
  console.log('Results: ' + results);
  return results;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/caolan/async?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question using the suggested module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using async queues:

```
var results = [];
var items = ['a', 'b', 'c']; 

// We assume items[] isn't empty, and create a queue
// to process each item.
var itemQueue = async.queue(function (item, nextItem) {
  // For each item get the bids
  Bid.findBids(2, item, function(err, bids){
    if (err) throw err; 

    // If no bids go to next item
    if (bids.length === 0) {
      nextItem();
    } else {
      // Otherwise loop through bids with another queue
      var bidQueue = async.queue(function (bid, nextBid) {
        User.findBidder(item.email, function(err, user){
          if(err) throw err;
          var bid = [];
          bid['user'] = user;            
          bid['item'] = item;     
          results.push(bid);
          nextBid();
        });
      });

      // When all bids are done, go to next item.
      bidQueue.drain = function() {
        nextItem();
      };

      // place all bids on the queue for this item.
      bidQueue.push(bids);
    }
  });
});

// When all items are done, print the results
itemQueue.drain = function () {
  console.log('Results: ');
  console.log(results);
}

// push all the items onto the queue - note that if items is 
// empty, drain() will never be called!
itemQueue.push(items);
```